# Android Studio does not automatically create the menu folder

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a new project in Android Studio but I've got a few problems with the menu folder:
First it seems like it is not created automatically, and second in the main_activity java project, I don't have the auto-generated method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
...    
}
```

My SDK version is 22. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpwIU.png)

Comment: why do not you create the folder then?

Comment: You know you can create folders... right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have selected "Empty Activity" when you created the project in Android studio. That template does not include a menu. If you need the menu auto generated for you and all boilerplate code you will need to select "Blank Activity" while generating project in Android Studio.

You can add the menu yourself later ofcourse even you have selected "Empty Activity"